# querySelectorAll is not working with data-srcset

Tags: javascript, jquery, attributes, selectors-api

I want to apply a class to all the horizontal imgs on the website.

I'm trying to use this function below but it doesn't work.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```js
$(function() {
  var images = document.querySelectorAll('[data-srcset]');

  for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
    if (images[i].naturalWidth > images[i].naturalHeight) {
      $(images[i]).addClass('horizontal');
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAAAAACH5BAEKAAEALAAAAAABAAEAAAICTAEAOw==" data-srcset="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/02/18/11/50/mountain-landscape-640617_960_720.jpg" alt=landscape>
```

Comment: what error r u getting in console

Comment: @Akshaypadwal No errors, it just doesn't apply that horizontal class.

Answer (score 2):

That is because the `data:...` image you provide is 1x1 and so the check for `images[i].naturalWidth > images[i].naturalHeight` fails.

Keep in mind that if you use the `srcset` attribute (*instead of `data-srcset`*) which is the default it will work as expected (*but you need to use the `load` event of the page*).

---

```js
$(window).load(function() {
  var images = document.querySelectorAll('[srcset]');

  for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
    if (images[i].naturalWidth > images[i].naturalHeight) {
      $(images[i]).addClass('horizontal');
    }
  }
})
```

```css
.horizontal{border:10px solid OliveDrab;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAAAAACH5BAEKAAEALAAAAAABAAEAAAICTAEAOw==" srcset="http://www.dummyimage.com/400x200" alt=landscape>

<img src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAAAAACH5BAEKAAEALAAAAAABAAEAAAICTAEAOw==" srcset="http://www.dummyimage.com/200x210" alt=landscape>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's better to replace `alt=landscape` with `alt="landscape"`.

both

```
var images = document.querySelectorAll('[data-srcset]');
```

and

```
var images = $('[data-srcset]');
```

works for me.

Your problem is if statement is not true. it's always go to `else`.

Try update your if statement by the following code.

```
if (images[i].naturalWidth > images[i].naturalHeight) {
    $(images[i]).addClass('horizontal');
    console.log(images[i]);
} else {
    console.log('else');
}
```

You'll see that it's always go to else.

Comment: can you provides html please. This is work for me when i try it.